# Android Make Image Slide to Outside of View

Tags: android, image, view, slide

I there, I want to make dissapear an image that is showing on my custom view, but I want it to dissapear to the left of the screen, slowly like a finger slide.

What I should use?

Change position of the image at each 100ms using the UI Thread?

Comment: This can help you: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Comment: That doesn't really help, because I want to do it to the image inside the view... not sliding the entire activity